# Ошибка unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Работаю с CI. Выполняю запрос:

```
function get_history($username) 
        {
            $where = "receiver=$username OR sender=$username";
            return $this->db->where($where)->order_by('id', 'DESC')->limit(10)->get("transactions");
        }
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'johndoe' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE `receiver` = `johndoe` OR `sender`
>   = `johndoe` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10

Что я делаю не так? Почему значение 'johndoe' в ошибке значится как колонка?
благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Колонка `receiver` и `sender` у вас строковые,так что и значения должны быть в них строками.Нужно было переменные обрамлять в строковые кавычки.

То есть результат должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE receiver = 'johndoe' OR sender = 'johndoe' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Иначе в пределах данного запроса будет искать колонку с подобным именeм (`johndoe`),и не находя его выдаёт вашу ошибку.

Решение:

```
function get_history($username) 
{
    $where = "receiver='{$username}' OR sender='{$username}'";
    return $this->db->where($where)->order_by('id', 'DESC')->limit(10)->get("transactions");
}
```